# mysql - how to return prepared statement resultset?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, execute

I'm trying to do a SELECT * from a table, where the name of that table is itself taken from another query. I think I'm tying myself in knots. Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT options_table INTO @tableName FROM registrant_fields WHERE id = 9;

SET @sql_text_1 = concat('CREATE TABLE tmp_options LIKE ', @tableName);
PREPARE stmt_1 FROM @sql_text_1 ;
EXECUTE stmt_1;

SET @sql_text_2 = concat('INSERT tmp_options SELECT * FROM ', @tableName);
PREPARE stmt_2 FROM @sql_text_2;
EXECUTE stmt_2;

SELECT * FROM tmp_options;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_2;
```

So... when I paste that lot into PHPMyAdmin and run it, I get the results of each statement appended respectively, and learn that yep, my "SELECT * FROM tmp_options;" has indeed got some rows. But how do I GET them??

All I want to do is drop that query into a PHP string and run it with mysqli_query(). Is that not going to work?

Comment: this is not actually a query, but rather set of queries. Also, I have a feeling that most of them quite useless and the business task can be solved a less toilsome way.

Comment: You have a... feeling? Are your spidey-senses tingling? Is there a disturbance in the force?

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about PHP, but I happen to know that mysqli_query() works with one SQL statement only (for security reasons).

I'd suggest you do (pseudo code, except SQL parts)

```
somePHPvariableForTableName = ("SELECT options_table FROM registrant_fields WHERE id = 9;");
query("CREATE TABLE whyDoIneedAtmpTable AS SELECT * FROM $somePHPvariableForTableName");
query("SELECT * FROM whyDoIneedAtmpTable;");
```

and that's it. No need for that extra `INSERT` step. And it's not clear, why and if you really need a temp table.